# Loading linux environment variables

Tags: linux, environment-variables, coreos

I have a set of environment variables and i would like to load it automatically on each startup. As of now i am doing the following:

In /etc/environment

```
export FLEETCTL_TUNNEL=10.77.189.179
```

In ~/.bashrc

```
source /etc/environment
```

But in theory export command if put in ~/.bashrc, should work right ?

Is there a preferred way of doing this ?

Comment: You probably more likely to get an answer over at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  Environment variables placed in `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`, & `/etc/environment` should all be read (but will be read by different components).  Technically `/etc/environment` is not POSIX compliant (which only means it cannot be expected to work on all POSIX systems).  Additionally, environment variables which need to be provided to individual services can be added to systemd.service units as specified in [man systemd.service](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)

An example of this in practice would be etcd:

```
core@littleguy ~ $ systemctl  cat etcd.service
# /usr/lib64/systemd/system/etcd.service
[Unit]
Description=etcd

[Service]
User=etcd
PermissionsStartOnly=true
Environment=ETCD_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/etcd
Environment=ETCD_NAME=%m
ExecStart=/usr/bin/etcd 
Restart=always
RestartSec=10s
```

In this case you can see that the value `ETCD_DATA_DIR` was set to "/var/lib/etcd" and the value `ETCD_NAME` was set to the machine ID of this host (as read from `/etc/machine-id` - "427483172c674b648b24f44bd133aeb7")